# When should I use the keyword super in Base class in python?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-forms, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to understand [this piece of code](https://github.com/bitlabstudio/django-review/blob/master/review/views.py) in python. From my understanding, `super` is used to call a base class function from derived class when you don't want to explicitly write the name of the base class. But as mentioned below, what does it mean if the base class itself uses `super`  to call some function?

```
class ReviewViewMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # some code
        return super(ReviewViewMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class ReviewCreateView(ReviewViewMixin, CreateView):
    # some code
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReviewCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I tried creating few sample classes like above but I get the expected "no such parameter" exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll notice that your class `ReviewCreateView` has *two* (direct) base classes.  `super` is necessary to make sure that the `dispatch` method gets called on *both* of those base classes.

Whenever a class is created, python looks at the inheritance tree and flattens it which creates something called the ["Method Resolution Order" (MRO)](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).  In this case, your MRO is probably<sup>1</sup>:

```
ReviewCreateView, ReviewViewMixin, CreateView, ..., object
```

What `super` does is it inspects the current MRO and it calls the method on the next class in the MRO.  Your call stack will look like:

```
ReviewCreateView.dispatch (super) -> ReviewViewMixin.dispatch (super) -> CreateView.dispatch
```

Now note that if `ReviewViewMixin` didn't have a `super` in there, the call stack would have ended with it.  However, since it has a `super` and the next class in the MRO is `CreateView`, `CreateView`'s dispatch method will also get called.

`super` can be tricky to really wrap your head around -- I'd suggest reading the ["super is Super"](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) article by Raymond Hettinger for some ideas and best-practices.

<sup><sup>1</sup>You can inspect the MRO by using [`inspect.getmro(ReviewCreateView)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro) or simply looking at `ReviewCreateView.__mro__`</sup>

Comment: This is absolutely simple and a brilliant explanation. Thank you so much. I spent way too much time in figuring out what was going on.